# Github pages is showing build error for my react app even after showing published in my terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

whenever I deploy my react app to github pages it is showing the following error.

> Your site is having problems building: Unable to build page. Please try again later

[image: Your site is having problems building: Unable to build page. Please try again later]

It was working fine even a week ago. This is the code of my **package.JSON** file

```js
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "homepage": "https://srijit2002.github.io/todoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.32.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you [searched](https://github.community/t/github-pages-builds-fail/10710/9) on Google for [similar issues](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites) that other people have had.

Comment: Yeah but I could not find any correct working solution